# Definition of "workstation" in Avahi Discovery

Tags: linux, avahi

When I used the Avahi Zeroconf Browser tool on my Lubuntu 16.04 machine, it lists only one of the machines on the LAN as a "Workstation".

What's the criteria for listing a LAN computer as a "Workstation" in this tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing a `_workstation._tcp` service being published by that host. (It doesn't have any other purpose except for making the computer show up in a list.) There is no special criteria; all entries correspond to some or other service published via DNS-SD.

This (and a HINFO record with similar purpose) can be enabled in `avahi-daemon.conf`, and used to be published by default but was recently disabled for privacy reasons.

```
[publish]
publish-workstation=yes
```

Comment: I think I recently got caught out by this in that my main Linux PC `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` had commented *formerly* default entries for these as `#publish-workstation=yes` and `#publish-hinfo=yes` but I had to **un**comment them in order to get the PC to show up as a workstation when I was using `avahi-browse -a -v` from my Raspberry Pi to try and find the PC!